# преобразование времени в UNIX формате в формат dd.mm.yy hh:mm:ss с помощью библиотеки 'time.h'

Tags: c

Пытаюсь преобразовать время в в UNIX формате в формат dd.mm.yy hh:mm:ss с помощью библиотеки 'time.h'.

Для этого сделал:

```
   time_t rawtime = (time_t)datatime;
   struct tm  ts;
   ts = *localtime(&rawtime);

   modifyFileHeaderList.date.day    = ts.tm_mday;
   modifyFileHeaderList.date.mounts = ts.tm_mon;
   modifyFileHeaderList.date.year   = ts.tm_year - 100;

   modifyFileHeaderList.time.hour   = ts.tm_hour;
   modifyFileHeaderList.time.min    = ts.tm_min;
   modifyFileHeaderList.time.sec    = ts.tm_sec;
```

Где datatime число формата uint32_t и равно '1619424306' что соответствует Mon Apr 26 2021 15:05:06 UTC но я получаю в поле часы 'ts.tm_hour' число '8' а должно быть '15'. Почему получаю '8' не понимаю.

Comment: Всё верно получаете. Смотрите здесь: https://www.unixtimestamp.com/ru/

Comment: А как понять какой часовой пояс ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> должно быть '15'. Почему получаю '8' не понимаю.

Видимо на твоей машине установлена зона UTC+7, а [`localtime()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime) возвращает локальное время, для перевода unix-таймстемпов в UTC есть [`gmtime()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/gmtime).

> А как понять какой часовой пояс ?

Вообще говоря, с точки зрения Си реализация локального времени платформозависима. И интерфейсов для этого не предусмотрено. На современных POSIX-системух информацию о временной зоне можно получить из глобальных переменных [`tzname`](http://ru.manpages.org/tzname/3) и `timezone`;

Comment: Забыл написать я пишу для микроконтроллера stm32h743. Без ОС. ОС моя и не поддерживает локацию времени. Вот нужно как-то записать время, а как вычислить часовой пояс не ясно.

Comment: "Временная зона" — это свойство **процесса**, а не системы.

Comment: @zhilenkov, смотри документацию/исходники своей libc... у тебя там newlib?...для времени в utc, опять же, просто используй `gmtime()`...